# Glassfish MySQL JNDI Lookup fails

Tags: mysql, glassfish, jndi, lookup

on Glassfish 4.1.1 Admin Interface I have setup a JDBC resource named jdbc/MySQL linked to a JDBC Connection pool named MySQL (modified the domain.xml manually first). The ping on the connection pool is successful. So far so good.

I modified web.xml and added:

```
<resource-ref>
 <description>DB Connection</description>
 <res-ref-name>jdbc/MySQL</res-ref-name>
 <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
 <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

And glassfish-web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/MySQL</res-ref-name>
  <jndi-name>jdbc/MySQL</jndi-name>
</resource-ref>
```

But in my J2EE WAR, when I do:

```
InitialContext ctx;
DataSource ds;

ctx = new InitialContext();
ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/MySQL");
```

The result is always Lookup failed.

Removing the java:comp/env/ did not help.

Any hint is appreciated! Thank you.

Regards
john

Comment: Did you check if the JDBC resource is enabled? Will it work if you remove resource-ref from both files (as the JNDI names in the app and container are equal)?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got it to work. Resource was enabled and the modification in web.xml and glassfish-web.xml is not really needed, I just did that in my many attempts to fix it.

But you know what the reason was? The slash in the JNDI name. I found out today when I pressed the save button in the admin panel of the resource and got the error 'resource jndi%2FMySQL does not exist'. I took that as a hint and name the resource only 'mysql'. That fixed it :) Can someone confirm that on glassfish 4.1.1.?

Due to the bug in the admin panel with adding new resources, I had to insert it into the domain.xml manually in the beginning. Maybe that was the reason? But the default resources are also saved with a slash...

Btw. the lookup is now:

```
ctx.lookup("mysql");
```